# TCP/IP connection on a specific interface

Tags: c++, winsock

I'd like to connect to a server using one of two network routes. How would one do this? I've Googled quite a bit, and the common answer is to fiddle with the routing table, however this won't help as the destination has a single IP address. Most of the examples feature a client with a single net card and a server with multiple NICs, but it's the opposite in this case.

The ForceBindIP app seems to be able to offer this type of functionality, so I guess it must be possible.

```
             +----->-------+
192.168.1.3  |      B      |          192.168.1.4
      +--------+      +--------+      +--------+
      | Client |      | Switch |-->---| Server |
      +--------+      +--------+      +--------+
192.168.1.2  |      A      |
             +----->-------+
```

I'll most likely be using C++ and winsock to do this. I'll need to be able to open a connection on a given route at will (i.e. must not be statically bound to a particular route). I'll be using plain ol' TCP/IP.

EDIT: Windows 7 client

Comment: On linux you can use SO_BINDTODEVICE (if you have two devices) or just plain bind() before connect to differentiate between local IPs.

Comment: Thanks, but using a Windows client

Comment: Windows bind has the same functionality, you specify which IP to bind to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx) function to bind the socket to either `192.168.1.3` or `192.168.1.2` before calling `connect()`, `ConnectEx()`, or `WSAConnect()`.  That tells the socket which specific interface to use for the outgoing connection.  For example:

```
SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

sockaddr_in localaddr = {0};
localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.3");
bind(s, (sockaddr*)&localaddr, sizeof(localaddr));

sockaddr_in remoteaddr = {0};
remoteaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
remoteaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.4");
remoteaddr.sin_port = 12345; // whatever the server is listening on
connect(s, (sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, sizeof(remoteaddr));
```

Alternatively:

```
addrinfo localhints = {0};
localhints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST | AI_NUMERICSERV;
localhints.ai_family = AF_INET;
localhints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
localhints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addrinfo *localaddr = NULL;
getaddrinfo("192.168.1.3", "0", &localhints, &localaddr);
bind(s, localaddr->ai_addr, localaddr->ai_addrlen);
freeaddrinfo(localaddr);

addrinfo remotehints = {0};
remotehints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST | AI_NUMERICSERV;
remotehints.ai_family = AF_INET;
remotehints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
remotehints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addrinfo *remoteaddr = NULL;
getaddrinfo("192.168.1.4", "12345", &remotehints, &remoteaddr);
connect(s, remoteaddr->ai_addr, remoteaddr->ai_addrlen);
freeaddrinfo(remoteaddr);
```

Comment: Does Indy support that on Windows?

Comment: @MehmetFide yes.  `TIdTCPClient` has `BoundIP` and `BoundPort(Min|Max)` properties for this exact purpose