# Application specific network interface in CEF3 based application

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, networking, chromium-embedded

I am writing a CEF3 based application. I have a requirement, where I can show available network interface and select any of them. Once I have selected the network interface all the traffic should route through that selected network interface. For example if I am having one Ethernet one wifi and one 3G network interface available in my system. and all communication is going through the default which is Ethernet. Now If I select wifi from the application, All communication within the application should go through wifi.
I searched a lot over net and figured out that using bind() function we can bind a specific IP address for communication. But, How can I achieve it in CEF3? 
I am new to CEF3 and never written any networking software.
I have already gone through below links-

[Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows)

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/

[TCP/IP connection on a specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697963/tcp-ip-connection-on-a-specific-interface)

I am writing cef3 application in win32/c++ so looking for the same.

Comment: I have already posted a question in cef3 forum. as below [link]http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12875

Comment: I am still looking for any solution or workaround for this... If anyone could provide a pointer would be great