# MQTT connect with specific interface like eth0/wlan0

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, mqtt

I used Paho - MQTT client library for MQTT connection, but it takes default interface to connect the internet.
Is there any MQTT API for the select specific interface like eth0/wlan0 and through it I connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paho MQTT C library does not seem to use [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) between [creating the socket](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/83cc318c96d508dd2ef26e87da23a858ff073b56/src/Socket.c#L651) and [calling `open()`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/83cc318c96d508dd2ef26e87da23a858ff073b56/src/Socket.c#L670), so the answer would be NO. Anyway it's opensource and from skimming the project, i went through at most 2 levels of abstraction between library interface and raw POSIX metal, so it should be fairly simple to add such functionality yourself. [A random answer describing socket binding howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697963/tcp-ip-connection-on-a-specific-interface).